Necessary and sufficient condition for $f(f(x))=x$
Based on the concept that $f$ is increasing then all the solutions of the equation $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ lie on the line $y=x$. I have two questions:
Can I solve $f(f(x))=x$ by taking $f(x)=x$ if $f$ is monotonic increasing?
Answer to this seems yes to me.
What are the necessary and sufficient condition for $f(f(x))=x$?
Is is necessary for it have an inverse or monotonic?
Can we not have an invertible function which satisfies $f(f(x))=x$

If $f\circ f(x)=x$ then it's clear that $f$ has an inverse (namely, $f$).

You can read this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29

$f$ must be both injective and surjective. So if it is continuous, it must be strictly monotone.

The answer depends on the choice of domain for $f$ and whether of not $f$ is continuous. For example, $f(x)=x$ when $x$ is rational and $f(x)=-x$ when $x$ is irrational is an involution of the real line.

For $f(f(x))=x$, it's not necessary for $f$ to be monotone. One easy counter-example is that, $f(x)=\begin{cases}1-x & x\in \{0,1\}\\x & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.
Let $(a_i,b_i)_{i\in I}$ be two "sequences" of pairs (acturally, $I$ can be uncountable) that is pairwise disjoint. Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}b_i & a_i=x\\a_i & b_i=x\\x & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, then $f(f(x))=x$. If we view $f$ as a permutation, then it must only contain permutation rings of two.
But It's necessary for $f$ to be invertible - its inverse is $f$.

Is it necessary that f must be it's self inverse?

@VikasSharma Recall the definition of inverse. If $f\circ g=Id$, then $f$ is the left inverse of $g$, $g$ is the right inverse of $f$. So $(f\circ f)(x)=x$ is exactly the definition of "$f$ is the inverse of itself".

There's a classic example.
$f_c(x) = x^2+c$
$f_c(x)=x\implies x^2+c-x=0\implies x = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4c}}{2}$
Note there are no real solutions for $c>1/4$. After which there are two solutions. This leads to the first part of a bifurcation diagram.
Solutions to $f_c(x)=x$ are called fixed points.
Solutions of $f_c(f_c(x))=x$ are periodic points of prime period two if they don't satisfy the previous equation.
$f_x(f_c(x))=x^4+2cx^2+c^2+c$
$f_x(f_c(x))=x \implies =x^4+2cx^2-x+c^2+c=0$
But we already have some solutions for $f_c(x)=x$ and they will satisfy the equation by inspection. But they are the fixed points from before and nothing new, so we want to skip them.
So $x^4+2cx^2-x+c^2+c=(x^2-x+c)(x^2+x+(c+1))$
$\implies x= \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-3-4c}}{2}$
So there are no solutions from $c>-3/4$ where another bifurcation occurs.
For a strict increasing function you can explore $g_c(x)=e^x+c$ by similar but numerical methods.
